# Celery socket handling

Tags: python, sockets, networking, rabbitmq, celery

**TL;DR**: What's the best practice for handling sockets in queued tasks?

I'm building a program which spawns celery tasks that handle **networking** operations.

One of the task group, handles the sending of data to specific sockets.
The problem is that, these tasks can **block** because the socket is **not ready** for writing.

So the **questions** are:

Is there a way to make the tasks be called as soon as the socket is writable?
Is there any best practice when it comes to handling sockets in queued tasks?